# How to add and remove points from a KDTreeSearcher in matlab

Tags: matlab, nearest-neighbor, knn, kdtree

**In MATLAB, is there a way to update the data points in a KDTreeSearcher?**

I'm starting with a tree with all N data points (a.k.a observations), and iteratively search a point from the tree, after a point is chosen I need to invalidate that point until a later stage.

The ability to build the tree with all the data (something like createns) and than flag points as valid/invalid or enabled/disabled is enough.

There will be a lot of removals (invalidations) and fewer additions (re-validations), when all points get invalidated the process ends.

I've seen the similar question about [scikit-learn kd-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002093/how-to-add-remove-data-points-to-from-a-scikit-learn-kd-tree), but it has no answers.